# Sound disappears after several reboots in 15.10 for ALC887 possibly because of Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, realtek, 15.10

Issue similar too https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238731/how-to-get-realtek-alc887-5-1-sound-detected-in-debian

After fresh new Ubuntu installation sound was working showing audio card as

```
...Audio Analog Stereo
```

but sound was successfully working for 5.1 sound system.

After several reboots and NVidia drivers installation sound stop working and prevoiusly mentioned device stop showing in sound configuration dialog.

Now devices are:

```
Built-in Audio digital Stereo IEC958
```

and other

```
GK104 HDMI ... 5.1 .
```

Also when OS is started there is a sound of drums which i can hear but after login there are no sound from browser audio for example.

So how to configure Gnome or KDE sound system to see desired 5.1 ALC887 audio as audio device.

It is also can be seen in

```
aplay -L
```

as

```
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
```